# Algorithm to find floors of multiples of the golden ratio

Tags: algorithms, integers, ceiling-and-floor-functions, continued-fractions, golden-ratio

What is an algorithm to calculate $\lfloor n\phi \rfloor$ given some integer $n$, where $\phi$ is the golden ratio?

I am thinking the easiest way will involve calculating multiples of its continued fraction representation, since the golden ratio has a simple representation as a continued fraction ($[1;1,1,1,\dots]$) and it is easy to find the floor of a continued fraction (it is just the integer part of the fraction). However, I do not know how to calculate multiples of a continued fraction.

Also, by algorithm, I mean that it could be efficiently implemented on a computer. The algorithm may use arbitrary-precision integer arithmetic. It should not, however, be sensitive to rounding errors if floating arithmetic is used (I would prefer to avoid floats entirely). Pseudocode would be great, but if you do not include it, that is fine.

Comment: This is [A000201](https://oeis.org/A000201) on OEIS.

Comment: @lulu good link. One thing to note though is that only covers the positive integers.

Comment: What's the order of $n$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust you mean the number of bits? $O(\log n)$

Comment: @PyRulez: are you kidding me ?

Answer (score 1):

The golden ratio satisfies $\phi^2-\phi-1=0$, so $n\phi$ is the positive solution to $x^2-nx-n^2=0$. You can use standard numerical methods (bisection, if you're in a hurry coding-wise, but you could save running time by starting with approximate Newton-Raphson until the deltas get small) to bracket the root between two neighboring integers.

Comment: Why the positive solution?

Comment: @PyRulez: Because the negative solution is $n(1-\phi)$.

Comment: wouldn't that be positive if $n$ is negative?

Comment: @PyRulez: I'm assuming that $n$ is positive. For negative multiples, you can use $$\lfloor (-n)\phi\rfloor = -\lfloor n\phi\rfloor -1 \qquad(n\ge 1),$$ since $n\phi$ is never an integer.

Comment: I quickly whipped up a [python script](https://repl.it/@ChristopherKing42/Floor-of-nphi) implementing this. Hitting "run" executes a demonstration. ([Backup](https://pastebin.com/5FVKeJdF) in case repl.it goes down.) Feel free to link or copy it into the answer if you think that would add to it.

Answer (score 0):

The Golden ratio can be approximated with arbitrary precision as the ratio of two consecutive Fibonacci numbers. These are easy to compute incrementally. Then compute and round

$$\left[n\frac{F_{k+1}}{F_k}\right].$$

It is even possible to compute $nF_k$ simultaneously to $F_k$. So the total cost is $2k$ additions and one division.

Comment: What value is $k$?

Comment: Unfriendly downvote.

Comment: @PyRulez Such that the error on $\phi$
is smaller than 
$1/n$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: obviously. The iterates are alternatively by default and by excess, so the sign is predictable.

Comment: Hmm, right, so if you get the same floor for two successive $k$s you'll know that is it. All in all, this probably has better asymptotic efficiency than my proposal, if you use matrix powers of $[{}^1_1\,{}^1_0]$ and a sub-quadratic multiplication algorithm to compute the Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: @HenningMakholm that depends on how efficiently $k$ can be calculated (unless you compute the floor for each $k$ like you said)

Comment: @PyRulez: $k$ must be a simple function of $\log_\phi n$, nothing critical. An overestimate by a few units should be no sin.

Comment: @PyRulez: You can estimate the error in Yves's approximation using $F_n=\frac{\phi^n+(-1)^{n+1}\phi^{-n}}{\sqrt 5}$. You will find that choosing $k$ as some _constant_ times $\log n$ will make the error less than $1$. Thus doing Yves' computation for this $k$ as well as $k+1$ will either tell you the final result immediately, or an integer $a$ such that $a<n\phi<a+2$. In the latter case, use my polynomial _once_ to compare $a+1$ to $n\phi$, and you're done.

Comment: (and even an overestimate of $k$ by a _factor_ of $2$ or $3$ will vanish in the asymptotic analysis anyway).